# Download PDF in Iframe with TCPDF generated File

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have a site where i display a TCPDF generated file in an Iframe. But when i try to download the PDF in the iframe overlay it downloads the tcpdf php file instead.

If i display the pdf file without the iframe (in a new tab for example) its working.

I`m using Google Chrome Verson 99.0.4844.51

Does anyone knows why this happens and how to fix this?

```
    <form id="moodleform" target="iframe" method="post" action="tcpdf-test.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="testid" value="test"/>
        </form>
        <iframe name="iframe" align="center" width="100%" height="1200px"></iframe>
```

Comment: What is the relation between your question and the code in your question? Could you show the code which is used when you _"download the PDF in the iframe overlay"_? How is this done?

Comment: @KIKO Software i dont have the code which is used when downloading the pdf file. I just use the download button in the pdf overlay.

Comment: OK, so you output a PDF with PHP. When the output is presented in an iframe, and you press the download button inside the PDF, you download its PHP code, but when the PDF is presented in its own browser window, the download gives the PDF? That's interesting, but I cannot reproduce that here. Normally visitors should not have access to the PHP code on your server.

Comment: Could you show all the headers, you use to identify the PHP file as a PDF, in your question?

Comment: @Kiko Software. You mean my tcpdf informations like $pdf->Output("'test KW'_'$year.pdf", 'I');

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, but it will do. You have some very weird quotes in your file name. Why? Try `$pdf->Output("test_KW_$year.pdf", 'I');` instead.

Comment: The file name is used in TCPDF to create the headers I talked about, those quotes might do something weird to the headers.

Comment: I changed the quotes to some simple string for testing and i get the same unusual behavior. Apart from that, its working when i display the pdf alone. the Program is running on an intern webserver could there be some settings which affect the iframe?

Comment: Oh, well, it was worth a try. I don't know about the settings. Sorry, I have no reasonable explanation for this behavior of Chrome. Does it occur in other browsers, like Firefox?

Comment: It works when I use Internet Explorer or Firefox... Seems like a Chrome problem

Comment: I still don't understand how a browser can get access to the PHP code on your server.